# Returning a downcasting type

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I've created an enum to manage the style of my app and I want that enum to return either a UIColor type or CAGradientLayer depending in the case. This is the code I have and actually it works fine but everytime I use it, I have to downcast. Is there a way I can return the value downcasted?

```
import UIKit

enum Theme {
    case darkBackground
    case lightBackground
    case gradientBackground
    case darkText
    case lightText
}

extension Theme {

    var value: Any {
        var instanceColor: UIColor = .clear
        var gradient: CAGradientLayer?
        switch self {
        case .darkBackground:
            instanceColor = .black
        case .lightBackground:
            instanceColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        case .darkText:
            instanceColor = .darkText
        case .lightText:
            instanceColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        case .gradientBackground:
            gradient = CAGradientLayer()
            gradient?.colors = [UIColor.init(hexString: "#516395").cgColor, UIColor.init(hexString: "#614385").cgColor]

        }

        return gradient != nil ? gradient : instanceColor
    }
}
```

**Example of use**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = Theme.lightBackground.value as? UIColor
}
```

Comment: can you show some code where you actually use `value`?

Comment: @luk2302 Updated with an example of use.

Comment: Don't think this is possible due to Swift's type system. A more elegant solution could be to extend `UIColor` and `CAGradientLayer` with static variables, i.e., `UIColor.light`, `UIColor.dark`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an `enum` that can be either a `UIColor` or a `CAGradientLayer` you can get rid of `Any`. See if this helps...

```
import UIKit

enum ColourOrGradient {
    case colour(UIColor)
    case gradient(CAGradientLayer)
    var colourGradient: (UIColor?, CAGradientLayer?) {
        switch self {
        case .colour(let c):
            return (c, nil)
        case .gradient(let g):
            return (nil, g)
        }
    }
}

enum Theme {
    case darkBackground
    case lightBackground
    case gradientBackground
    case darkText
    case lightText
}

extension Theme {

    var value: ColourOrGradient {
        switch self {
        case .darkBackground:
            return ColourOrGradient.colour(.black)
        case .lightBackground:
            return ColourOrGradient.colour(UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1))
        case .darkText:
            return ColourOrGradient.colour(.darkText)
        case .lightText:
            return ColourOrGradient.colour(UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1))
        case .gradientBackground:
            let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
            gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor] // Your `.hexString` not supplied
            return ColourOrGradient.gradient(gradient)
        }
    }
}

var gradient: CAGradientLayer?
var colour: UIColor?
(colour, gradient) = Theme.lightBackground.value.colourGradient
```

Of course, you could also do this:

```
import UIKit

enum Theme {
    case darkBackground
    case lightBackground
    case gradientBackground
    case darkText
    case lightText
}

extension Theme {

    var value: (UIColor?, CAGradientLayer?) {
        switch self {
        case .darkBackground:
            return (.black, nil)
        case .lightBackground:
            return (UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1), nil)
        case .darkText:
            return (.darkText, nil)
        case .lightText:
            return (UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1), nil)
        case .gradientBackground:
            let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
            gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor] // Your `.hexString` not supplied
            return (nil, gradient)
        }
    }
}

var gradient: CAGradientLayer?
var colour: UIColor?
(colour, gradient) = Theme.lightBackground.value
```

Comment: This could benefit from an example showing how to use the two types of results.

Comment: @rmaddy, I'm not entirely sure I know how the OP was going to use it, but have updated the answer to give a possible scheme.

Comment: It does not work either, It return a ColourOrGradient type so you can not assign it either UIColor or CAGradientLayer type.

Comment: So... with Swift being strongly typed, how are you going to assign it to "either UIColor or CAGradientLayer"?